# Using simple auth and form based access to controllers

Tags: spring, authentication, grails, spring-security

Suppose I have a Grails 2.4.3 application, with one controller:

```
@Secured(['ROLE_USER'])
Class HeyController {
    def doSomething() { render "Do something" }
    def doSomethingElse() { render "Do something else" }
}
```

I would like to tell the underlying Spring Security framework to secure access like so:

- Form based login for `http://myhost:8080/app/hey/doSomething`
- Basic HTTP authentication for `http://myhost:8080/app/hey/doSomethingElse`

I know it's possible to configure this access using vanilla Spring security using two `<http>` configuration sections for each access pattern in the security context configuration file.

Therefore, there must be some way to setup Spring Security via Grails right? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

... nevermind *facepalm*. It seems to be the case:

http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/authentication.html

I'll mark the answer as soon as I get it working in practice. Thanks!